# Selenium Python Help Getting element of a form

Tags: python, selenium

Iv been trying to get the form elements on this website and for some reason I cant get them. Iv tried every way I can think of. I would really appreciate some help.

Here is my latest attempt

`inputs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@type='text']")`

[Here](https://www.ownyourprep.com/bts-form) is the website.

Thanks in advance.

Edit : [Github link](https://github.com/WilPermenter/SignUpBot/blob/reformat/FratThing.py) for project

Edit : Ok so I found out that if you go straigt to website that the btn points to then it works. So I am assuming that slenium does not automaticly update to the HTML of the current page. How does one do this?

Comment: What is the error what you get and and you show some more code?

Comment: The xpath seems fine. I am able to find elements in DevTools. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Let me update the github and Ill put the link and basicly i get an error saying "No Such Element"

Comment: I think element Id id dynamic value.Try some other attribute which is static on the page.It should work.

Comment: @KajalKundu I think I have tried just about every useful attribute.

Comment: can share the html where your input field located.

Comment: i updated the answer, please check it

Answer (score 1):

if you are getting 'NoSuchElementException', try using conditional wait before you do find_element. When you are loading another page wait until the element is visible and can be interacted.
Guide for that is [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Comment: This worked for the last problem I posted about thanks.

Answer (score 0):

check if the element is inside in iform, if so use

```
driver.switchTo().frame("framename")
```

EDIT

Focus on something unique in the tag. For your example use the class name used in the div. Do not use the ID tag identifier as it changes over time.

```
//*[contains(@class, 'ginput_container ginput_container_text')]/following::*[contains(text(),'Email')]/following::div[1]/descendant::input
```

Comment: saddly it is not in a frame, there is some javascript  and the text box is in a gform if you know anything about that

Comment: still getting no such element. Im assuming to implement that I need to just copy/paste it in the ()